# C++ multi window program - Create button on second window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, multi-window

So I've found a few multi-winodw tutorials/lessons but none of them seem to touch on my problem.

I'm trying to create a button on the second window, and not the other.

Here's my code (excluding the unnecessary stuff)

```
HWND hWindow1;
HWND hWindow2;
HINSTANCE hInstGlobal;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
...WindowClass / RegisterClass...

//HWND hWindow1;
hWindow1 = CreateWindow("WinProg", "Window_1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
    0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

//HWND hWindow2;
hWindow2 = CreateWindow("WinProg", "Window_2", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
    150, 50, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ...show/update windows...

...MessageLoop...
}

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(uiMessage)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        {                      
            HWND hButton;
            hButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "PUSH ME NOW",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                50, 200, 150, 20,
                hWindow2, (HMENU) 1,
                hInstGlobal, NULL);
        }
```

No buttons are created using this code.

as for my debugging, I can create a button on the first window by changing hWindow2 under WM_CREATE to hWindow1. But that's not what I want. I can however create a button on the second window by leaving it as hWindow2, but changing the message event to WM_PAINT...

I don't understand what's going on, and I'd prefer not to settle with a work around.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `WinProc()` used for both windows? in that case, you'll need to create the button on `WM_CREATE` only when `hWnd == hWindow2`

Comment: @EdwardClements Yes, I've tried that as well. I get the exact same results.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the obvious way to create a button on `hWindow2`?

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    ...WindowClass / RegisterClass...

    //HWND hWindow1;
    hWindow1 = CreateWindow("WinProg", "Window_1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        0, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    //HWND hWindow2;
    hWindow2 = CreateWindow("WinProg", "Window_2", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        150, 50, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    HWND hButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "PUSH ME NOW",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        50, 200, 150, 20,
        hWindow2, (HMENU) 1,
        hInstGlobal, NULL);

   ...show/update windows...

   ...MessageLoop...
}

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uiMessage)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Really not sure why you're trying to create the button in code that is being used by both `hWindow1` and `hWindow2`. Reduces the need for global variables too.

Comment: This would be the obvious way to create a button, and it works just fine. I just have this thing about needing to understand why something doesn't work when it should :/ Never know when it's going to bite you in the long run.